# regex parenthesis OR digit start of line

Tags: java, regex, string, object

I'm new to regex and trying to get this statement to pass. What I'm trying to do is check the first character or two from the string.

I want to see that if it starts with a number then the statement will be true. I also want to check that if the first character is a "(" then i want to check that the next number is a digit too.

So far I've got:

```
if (str.matches("^[(?\d")){
return true;
```

but this doesn't seem to work. ^ for anchoring to start, (? to check for optional parenthesis and then check if it's a digit afterwards. How have i stuffed up?

So 0800, (0800, (09, 09, should pass where as *08, (*0, AB, (AB, *AB should fail.

Thanks

Comment: Omit the square bracket.  I'm not sure what you think it does.

Comment: I removed it and it's still not working here. Only matches the one with the parenthesis and not the others. Tried escaping the parenthesis but still didn't work.

http://iforce.co.nz/i/qn1rwgii.bf2.jpg

Comment: I would go into more detail for you, but I believe @hwnd has already posted a correct answer, so I won't bother.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the opening square bracket and escape the metacharacters. Also, `matches()` tells whether or not the entire string matches the given regular expression. So, you need to add the token `.*` afterwards to greedily match every single character in the string.

```
if (str.matches("\\(?\\d.*")) { ... }
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/dUPWdi)

Comment: So if I substringed before to get the first two elements of the string, I wouldn't need to use the `.*` ?

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. Few questions:

I don't understand the first backslash. Why are you escaping the whole thing? Shouldn't you only want to escape the parenthesis?

Also why are you escaping the digit with `\\d` , shouldn't `\d` suffice? Why have you put `.*` at the end? Doesn't this mean zero or more of any character? Thanks

Comment: You have to double escape in Java. `(` is a metacharacter and `\d` is the regex token. `.*` at the end will consume all characters afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick:

```
^\d.*|^\(\d.*
```

In Java, with escaping of backslashes:

```
if (str.matches("^\\d.*|^\\(\\d.*"))
```

Comment: I think you need to have another start-of-line `^` after the OR `|`.  Otherwise, you will match something like `*AB(5`.

Comment: Actually, since you're using `matches`, the `^` characters aren't needed at all.